# How to get public ssh key from headless Ubuntu Server (no gui) to github deploy key

Tags: github, virtualbox, ssh-keys, ubuntu-18.04

I have built a headless Ubuntu Server 18.04 (without GUI). This is a simulated environment built in VirtualBox meant to simulate a production scenario that I am faced with configuring very soon. The production environment will be remote and access via a VPN. Please notes that VirtualBox is not part of the production scenario.

I have created a private/public ssh key pair for using in GitHub so I can add a new deploy key

I need to be able to get a copy of the public key to add to GitHub.

There is no clipboard with a headless server via terminal. I tried installing and configuring `xclip`/`xsel` to behave like `pbcopy`/`pbpaste`. This works great on `Ubuntu` with a GUI but doesn't work on a headless server via terminal.

Trying to use `xclip` like this:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

results in:

```
Error: Can't open display: :0
```

I tried getting OpenSSH up and running. I'm not an SSH guru and haven't gotten that to work.

Are there any other ways to get that ssh public key from the headless server? It is a remote server with no physical access.

Comment: Did you try ssh-copy-id? You can also cat the public key in terminal, mark it and simply copy &paste

Comment: Moved to Super User, thanks.

Comment: @h__ there is no clipboard, unable to copy and paste.

Comment: You didn't *move* it to [su], you have **copied** it there. Please delete this copy! Crossposting is forbidden.

Comment: If you have shell access you can copy and paste whatever you want.

Comment: @h__, that is not correct. There is no clipboard, copy and paste aren't available. Installing xsel and xclip don't work either. I can cat the key to the terminal but still can't copy it. Also, VirtualBox isn't the problem. As stated above, virtualbox is not part of the production scenario and doesn't factor into the solution. I ended up ftp'ing the public key to a remote server. It's a hack but worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My solution:**
I ended up ftp'ing the public key to a remote server. It's a hack but worked.